# How to use existing Symfony FormType in Sonata Admin Bundle configureFormFields?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

SonataAdminBundle gives a method `configureFormFields` when you extend the `Admin` class.

That method takes a `FormMapper` class.

For the entity that I have created this class for, I have already built a `FormType` class in the typical Symfony fashion.

How can I use that class instead of having to define the form properties again using the `FormMapper`?

Comment: configureFromFields the same as old fashion public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_name')

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{        
    $form = new ReviewFormType();
    $form->buildForm($formMapper->getFormBuilder(),array());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to the exact same thing today (defined a custom form type and tried to use in sonata) after hours of finding a clean way, i came up with this:

```
formMapper->add('your_field', new YourType($your_params), array(                    
                ), array('type' => 'form'))
```

Replace `your_field` with your field name,

`new YourType` with your custom field type and

`$your_params` with your field's constructor's parameters,

the fourth parameter `array('type' => 'form')` is very important, it tells sonata about what type your form is actually (sonata wont determine automatically from your type's object) my custom field extends the `form` type (it is an embedded form with its own fields) so i specify that, if your type extends something else then specify that, and hopefully it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for the exact same thing and eventually found the following in the docs:

> You can add Symfony `FormBuilderInterface` instances to the
>   `FormMapper`. This allows you to re-use a model form type. When adding
>   a field using a `FormBuilderInterface`, the type is guessed.
>
> Given you have a `PostType` like this:
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
> use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
>
> class PostType extends AbstractType
> {
>     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
>     {
>         $builder
>             ->add('author', EntityType::class, [
>                 'class' => User::class
>             ])
>             ->add('title', TextType::class)
>             ->add('body', TextareaType::class)
>         ;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> you can reuse it like this:
>
> ```
> use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
> use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
> use App\Form\PostType;
>
> class Post extend AbstractAdmin
> {
>     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
>     {
>         $builder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getFormFactory()->createBuilder(PostType::class);
>
>         $formMapper
>             ->with('Post')
>                 ->add($builder->get('title'))
>                 ->add($builder->get('body'))
>             ->end()
>             ->with('Author')
>                 ->add($builder->get('author'))
>             ->end()
>         ;
>     }
> }
> ```

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#adding-a-formbuilderinterface