# Symfony 4: Use existing form type class in Sonata's configureFormFields method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896885/how-to-use-existing-symfony-formtype-in-sonata-admin-bundle-configureformfields/49750335#49750335) I can pull individual form elements from the type's builder into the form mapper [as described in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#adding-a-formbuilderinterface):

> You can add Symfony `FormBuilderInterface` instances to the
>   `FormMapper`. This allows you to re-use a model form type. When adding
>   a field using a `FormBuilderInterface`, the type is guessed.
>
> Given you have a `PostType` like this:
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
> use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
> use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
>
> class PostType extends AbstractType
> {
>     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
>     {
>         $builder
>             ->add('author', EntityType::class, [
>                 'class' => User::class
>             ])
>             ->add('title', TextType::class)
>             ->add('body', TextareaType::class)
>         ;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> you can reuse it like this:
>
> ```
> use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
> use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
> use App\Form\PostType;
>
> class Post extend AbstractAdmin
> {
>     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
>     {
>         $builder = $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getFormFactory()->createBuilder(PostType::class);
>
>         $formMapper
>             ->with('Post')
>                 ->add($builder->get('title'))
>                 ->add($builder->get('body'))
>             ->end()
>             ->with('Author')
>                 ->add($builder->get('author'))
>             ->end()
>         ;
>     }
> }
> ```

However, this feels clunky if all you want is for Sonata to use that exact type as is.

I was therefore wondering if there is a shorthand that tells sonata to simply use the entire form type as is.

Something like:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->mapForm((new PostType()));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to 100% understand what you want, do you mean, you have a form `FooType` and want to use in in another form ?

Comment: Sort of - Sonata Admin lets you define what form fields you want to provide to a user of the CMS when adding / editing a given Entity. This is done via configureFormFields() and carries a certain amount of duplication in that you need to re-list all the fields that you have already defined in your FormType that's used for the public facing form. If this is a longer more complex form this leads to a fair amount of duplicate code that I am looking to avoid. It feels like you should be able to say "Hey Sonata, use this FormType as is!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the shorter version using `inherit_data` might be what you are looking for.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html

From: [How to inherit FormType in Sonata Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847839/how-to-inherit-formtype-in-sonata-admin)

With the `Post` example

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use App\Form\PostType;

class PostAdmin extend AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add(
                'post',  // name does not seem to matter
                PostType::class, 
                [
                    'inherit_data' => true,
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

Using `PostAdmin` (and `PostType`) to map a child record in a 1:m relationship works too, but has problems with `inline` options and the [table view does not seem to render it in separate columns as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvSUY.png)

```
// Thread 1:m Post

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
    ...
 */
class Thread
{
    protected $title = '';

    /**
     * @var Post[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(...)
     */
    protected posts;
}
```

```
class Post extend AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->
            ->with('Thread')
            ->add('title')
            ->add(
                'posts',
                'sonata_type_collection',
                [
                    'label'        => 'Posts',
                    'required'     => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ],
                [
                    'edit'     => 'inline', // does not seem to work
                    'inline'   => 'table',  // takes up one column in table
                    'multiple' => true,     // one row per entry
                ]
            );
    }
}
```